# Angular 2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null

Tags: angular

I apply code from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html and run good except page hero detail: http://localhost:3000/detail/12

[image: error]

File app.module.ts

```
import './rxjs-extensions';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { HeroSearchComponent }  from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [ {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }, HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

File hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
               .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }

  delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  update(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
    return this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

File index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help me with first demo in Angular 2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes). Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it like http://localhost:3000/detail/:id ? The `:id` must be replaced by the id of a hero.

Comment: I try http://localhost:3000/detail/12 but not run :(

Comment: have you made a routing link for `/heroes`?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the backtick ` syntax wrapping your template string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but it seems that it's not complete Url:

```
private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api
```

Check out if you are getting complete Url.

Comment: I try but not run :(

Answer (score 0):

according to the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#heroes-and-http), you should change

`private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api`

to

`private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api`