# Angular "Collection '${id}' not found" during Heroes Tour

Tags: angular

I ran into the same issue as the person who posted this problem.

[Angular2 Tutorial (Tour of Heroes): EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40757450/angular2-tutorial-tour-of-heroes-exception-response-with-status-404-not-fou#comment69690818_40757450)

Before coming here, I eventually figured out that I needed to use the tick marks instead of single quotes around the URL.

Can anyone explain why that is? I'm unable to ask the person who answered in the above posting.

Comment: You'll want to learn about template literals: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Oh. Well that makes a lot more sense. It's like special notation that incorporates variables and strings without the need for string concatenation. Thanks!